# replace string in specific line in text file in Python

Tags: python, replace

I need to replace a string in several lignes of a text file, but only if it find another string in the ligne...

something like that:

```
last_file = 'path\\inFile.nk'.replace('/','\\')
output_file = 'pat\\OutFile.nk'.replace('/','\\')

f1 = open(last_file, 'r')
f2 = open(output_file, 'w') 

for line in f1:
    for word in line:
        if word == '/string_to_search/':
            print line
            f2.write(line.replace('OldString', 'NewSting'))
        else:
            f2.write(word)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Thanks for any help because i've done that without success !

Comment: Presumably this code does not work correctly. What is wrong with it? How does it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
f1 = open("last_file.txt", 'r+')
f2 = open("output_file.txt", 'w+') 

keyString = '/string_to_search/'
oldString = "any other language"
newString = "python"

f2.write("".join([i.replace(oldString, newString) if keyString in i else i for i in f1.readlines()]))

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

For example this input file

```
random line
/string_to_search/ any other language
/string_to_search/ something?
```

writes the following to the output file:

```
random line
/string_to_search/ python
/string_to_search/ something?
```

Comment: whaou thanks a lot ironkey it's working :) !!!!!

Comment: you save my night thank you

Comment: you're very welcome, if the answer helped you can click the checkmark to accept it for future users. thanks for asking and happy coding!